# PgRouting : Shortest path starting from the closest vertex not the closest node

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, nodes, dijkstra

I am currently working on a routing solution with PgRouting (Dijkstra's algorithm), but the shortest path it creates always start from the nearest nodes generated from the edge table, and sometimes the distance between the node and the point is too long(4km or more) and it makes my calculations wrong.
Is there a way to calculate the shortest path from the closest line vertex to my starting point?
I included a picture to clarify more my problem

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While still not in the *official release*, the [`withPoints` family of functions](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.1/en/withPoints-family.html) is in a stable state since pgRouting 2.2 (?) and provides a dynamic interface for temporary nodes in a graph, i.e. *routing between arbitrary points*.

The key here is the `points_sql` where you specify the closest edge to any of your temporary nodes, and the fraction of line length their closest point is located at.

Assuming `points_table(id INT, geom GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326))` holds all custom source and target points, you can

- either query dynamically, i.e. running

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM   pgr_withPoints(
           '<edges_sql>',
           'SELECT pnt.id AS pid,
                   edg.edge_id,
                   edg.fraction
            FROM   points_table AS pnt
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
              SELECT <id> AS edge_id,
                     ST_LineLocatePoint(<geom>, pnt.geom) AS fraction
              FROM   <edges_table>
              ORDER BY
                     <geom> <-> pnt.geom
              LIMIT  1
            ) AS edg',
          -1, -2,
          details := TRUE
        )
  ;
  ```

  would route **between `points_table.id` 1 & 2** [*]
- or add and update the required fields to your `points_table` in advance for more performance; the above `points_sql` query can be applied for the update

With the `details` parameter set to `TRUE`, the function treats all dynamic nodes from the `points_sql` (i.e. all other than those used as `source` & `target`) as 'normal' nodes of the graph in the result set; setting to `FALSE` would return only edges and vertices of the `edge_sql` (but always including start and/or end node if they are of the `points_sql`).

---

[*] for all temporary nodes passed in via `points_sql`, the function will use **negative `pid` values** as input as well as in the result set!

Comment: Nice explanation! We could add your example to the gRouting documentation.

Comment: @dkastl thx, and by all means, please go ahead if this would add value to the docs!

Comment: I really want to thank you for your answer, you opened my eyes on something I had no idea about

Comment: @Ismail share our knowledge, learn from each other; it can be so simple and effective! You are very welcome, if you think this answers your question, consider accepting the answer by activating the little tick symbol next to it.