# PgRouting : pgr_withpoints issue

Tags: pgrouting

Following my [Other Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377630/pgrouting-shortest-path-starting-from-the-closest-vertex-not-the-closest-node) about non-network integrating routing, I have tried the with-points functions using the code proposed in the answer.

The problem is I don't get the shortest path using these functions

For clarification the pink polyline represents the With-points result and the green one represents Dijkstra's result

**Edited**

The code I used to  calculate the with_points route is

```
SELECT *
FROM   pgr_withPoints(
         'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(the_geom)  as cost FROM vr',
         'SELECT pnt.id AS pid,
                 edg.edge_id,
                 edg.fraction
          FROM   points_table AS pnt
          CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
            SELECT id AS edge_id,
                   ST_LineLocatePoint(the_geom, pnt.geom) AS fraction
            FROM   vr
            ORDER BY
                   the_geom <-> pnt.geom
            LIMIT  1
          ) AS edg',
        -888888, -607,
        details := TRUE
      );
```

vr is my edge table, -888888 and -607 are start and end point id
[image]

Comment: With just a screenshot it's not possible to guess what could be wrong. Could you also post your queries and even better, could you provide a sample network to reproduce your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified a `cost` but not a `reverse_cost`, so the [default](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.0/en/pgr_withPoints.html#inner-query) of `-1` is used, meaning the segment is ignored.

You can try with

`'SELECT id, source, target, st_length(the_geom)  as cost, st_length(the_geom)  as reverse_cost FROM vr',`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now, but I need more information about the reverse cost, because as much as I know even if you don't insert the reverse cost in the Dijkstra you get the shortest path, and the with points function is based on dijkstra? am I wrong ?

Comment: For both functions, you can use `directed=false` and then only use the `cost`