# Locations not picked up by pgrouting

Tags: pgrouting

I have some point locations (solid black points) that I am performing network analysis on, but not all of them are being analyzed by pgrouting.  The black points with purple rings have been analyzed and the solid black points have not.

Why would some points be analyzed and others not, especially for the cases when they are beside each other?

[image: analyzed and unanalyzed points]

Comment: maybe pgrouting has not been instructed to use the network in both directions? see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381392/pgrouting-pgr-withpoints-issue/381421#381421)

Comment: @ JGH I think the answer to my question is in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377630/pgrouting-shortest-path-starting-from-the-closest-vertex-not-the-closest-node?noredirect=1&lq=1)